# No primitive roots modulo $N = pqr ( p , q , r$ all primes$)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p,q,r$ be distinct prime numbers. I tried to prove that there is no primitive root modulo $N = p\cdot q\cdot r$ without much success. I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the solution.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Use $\mathbb{Z}/(N) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p)\times \mathbb{Z}/(q) \times \mathbb{Z}/(r)$ if all three are different. (The isomorphism is a ring isomorphism, in particular, the group of units is the product of the unit groups in the factors.) If $p = q = r > 2$, then there are primitive roots, as in the case $p = 2 < q = r$.

Comment: I've edited my question, r , p , q are all different. How could I use isomorphism to solve the question ?

Comment: It suffices to prove that if $p' \neq q'$ are ODD primes, there is no primitive root $\pmod{p'q'}$, which follows from the fact that $2| \phi(p')$ and $2|\phi(q')$.

Comment: "there is no primitive root (modp′q′), which follows from the fact that 2|ϕ(p′) and 2|ϕ(q′)"  - why does it happen ? thanks for the answer

Comment: Same reasoning as in my answer. Try to follow the hint and ask if you get stuck.

Comment: One can also use CRT to show there are at least four square roots of $1$ corresponding to the solutions to the system $x\equiv\pm1\bmod p,q,r$ (signs varying independently, eight possible configurations) (not necessarily eight solutions since one of $p,q,r$ may be $2$ and $1\equiv-1$ mod $2$). This corresponds to at least three subgroups of order $2$, and cyclic groups have a unique subgroup of each possible order, so the group of units mod $pqr$ cannot be cyclic, hence no generator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $N=p_1p_2p_3$ with pairwise coprime primes $p_i$ and $a\in\mathbb Z$, such that $a$ and $N$ are coprime. Use

- the multiplicativity of $\varphi$
- $\varphi$ is even for odd primes

to prove for each $i=1,2,3$, that
 $$a^{\frac 12 \cdot \varphi(N)}\equiv 1\pmod{p_i}$$
Then, it follows, since the $p_i$ are pairwise coprime, that
 $$a^{\frac 12 \cdot \varphi(N)}\equiv 1\pmod{N}$$

**Follow-up task:** If you solved this, then you prove similarly, that there are no primitive roots for $N=pq$ with distinct *odd* primes $p,q$.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what do you mean by (a,N) ?

Comment: Short notation for $\gcd(a,N)$.

Comment: how could I prove that for each i=1,2,3, that a12⋅φ(N)≡1(modpi) ?

Comment: Take for instance $i=1$. At least one of $p_2$ and $p_3$ will be odd, now take a look at $$a^{\frac{1}{2}\varphi(N)}=\left(a^{\varphi(p_1)}\right)^{\frac12\varphi(p_2) \cdot \varphi(p_3)}=\left(a^{\varphi(p_1)}\right)^{\frac{(p_2-1)(p_3-1)}{2}}\pmod{p_1}$$